# Plot in a for loop?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Is there a way to dynamicaly plot lines inside a for loop?

I want to do something like that (but obviously got "Cannot use 'plot' in local scope."):

```
for i = 1 to steps-1
    plot(height * i, color=color.green, linewidth=1)
```

Comment: No, this cannot be done in Pine. Like you said, plot cannot be used in a local scope. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `plot()` function in the local scope, but you can use `line.new` as in the example below:

```
//@version=4
study("Line plot in local scope")

f_lineLoop(_i) => 
    var line _line = na 
    line.set_y1(_line, _i) 
    line.new(time, _i, time + 1, _i, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.blue, line.style_solid, 1)

if barstate.islast
    for _i = 0 to 10
        f_lineLoop(_i)
```

[image]